# Is it possible to get BLE Mac of own device in React-Native(iOS&Android)?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I need to get my own device's MAC address which I thought should be really simple but after some research it seems likely impossible.

**Any one had any experience on this before?** I need to get the BLE MAC on both OS.

Comment: using `react-native-ble-plx` you can scan but not sure if you can get your own mac address using that library.

Comment: @CoolSolutions I dont think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get your own MAC address on iOS. It has never been possible to get the Bluetooth MAC.  In the past developers used the WiFi MAC address as a unique device identifier.  Apple has now ensured that MAC addresses are inaccessible as a privacy protection.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's pathetic. It is important for privacy; some app developers abused MAC addresses for identification. Remember it isn't "you" that sees the MAC address, it is some app running on your device and while your app may not do the wrong thing, others might, so Apple closes the hole.  Also, other devices don't see your MAC either without connecting as the MAC addresses is randomised while advertising.  The only way you can get an identifier is to connect to a Bluetooth service and read it from a characteristic.

Comment: There is lots of good information here https://bluetrace.io/. The new tracing capabilities that Apple and Google are working on ease some restrictions for the purposes of contact tracing, but there are still identifier lifetimes and randomisation

Comment: Seems like I am out of luck, there is absolutely nothing out there that allows me to advertise my custom id to others via BLE or WIFI.

Comment: Wifi is a different question,  but you need the devices to be on the same wifi network.

Comment: So you are saying I can scan using RN with wifi?

Comment: You could use Bonjour networking (multicast) to have devices advertise a service over IP and to scan for devices advertising that service. You need the devices to be on the same network, so they could be hundreds of meters away from one another in case contact tracing is your goal.

Comment: my goal is to measure the distance how close are they with each other, can I do that via Wifi?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211983/discussion-between-paulw11-and-dfgd).